# Changing Menu active class with Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to change the class of a menu item to "active" depending on the page I'm currently on. I have a master page with the menu. A menu item looks like this:

I'm using this code:

```
    string thisURL = this.Page.GetType().Name.ToString();
    switch (thisURL)
    {
        case "ps4_aspx":
            menuPS4.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
            break;
    }
```

This works fine, but I can't get it working when the pages are in subfolders. For example, if I were to move PS4.aspx from root to a subfolder "Games", it doesn't work. I tried a couple of things, including this:

```
case "games/ps4_aspx"
```

Nothing happens. How do I make this work with subfolders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you need to change the class depending on the page you are on, you will need to obtain the URL of the page in a different way in your code. Using `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` would give you the complete Uri for the page, and then you can extract the file name from it as shown [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1730869.aspx?get%20file%20name%20from%20url).

Hope this helps.